# How to compile stock android for your phone

Tags: android, compilation, cross-compiling

Are there any instructions or pointers on how to get started to compile the AOSP 2.3 branch for HTC phones? I am looking at compiling and getting a vanilla OS for myself and later on putting on some custom apps.

I have followed the link http://source.android.com/source/ here and I am able to get the emulator build to compile ('full-eng'). Any pointers anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd reccommend you go to http://xda-developers.com for this. Their forum is focused on Android modifications, such as the one you're looking for, and someone there may be able to help you out. Someone might also have already done it and posted instructions.